# GBQ AUthenticate using JSON

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-authentication

I am retrieving the credentials for a GBQ service_account to authenticate and use GBQ. The credentials come with a private_key, client_id, token_uri, project_id and some other information. I am trying to create a client like this

```
const gbqCredentials = decodeKey(credentials),
bigQuery = new BigQuery(JSON.parse(gbqCredentials.toString()));
```

But i get th next exception:
{"message":"Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.."}

Comment: What does this do `decodeKey(credentials)` and what is the structure of `gbqCredentials`? And i think it should be more like this `... new BigQuery({ projectId: '...', credentials: <the content of json keyfile from google>, scopes: [...] })`

Comment: decodeKey is a function to decode the credentials as are saved encoded, AFter this I get a JSON with the next structure: 
{"type": "xxx", "project_id": "xxx", "private_key_id": "xxx", "private_key": "xxx", "client_email": "xxx", "client_id": "xxx", "auth_uri": "xxx", "token_uri": "xxx", "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "xxx", "client_x509_cert_url": "xxx"}

Comment: @Molda thank you so much, projectId parameter solved the issue

Comment: @Sebastián Can you post a response describing how you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue I passed the credentials on a JSON and added a parameter projectId (Which I didn't add before).

```
decodedCredentials = decodeKey(credentials);
const gbqCredentials = JSON.parse(decodedCredentials.toString());
bigQueryInstance = new BigQuery({credentials: gbqCredentials, projectId: `projectId`});
```